# Prove $\sum_{n=1}^\infty(\frac{1}{a_{2n-1}}-\frac{1}{a_{2n}})$ convergent

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, functions, sequence-of-function

Let $(a_n)_{n=1}^\infty$  Let be a positive, increasing, and unbounded sequence. Prove that the series:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac{1}{a_{2n-1}}-\frac{1}{a_{2n}}\right)$$

convergent.

---

We know that since $a_n$ is increasing and unbounded, than $\lim_{n \to \infty}a_n=\infty$, so I want to apply that to say that, $\sum_{n=1}^\infty(\frac{1}{a_{2n-1}}-\frac{1}{a_{2n}})$ is decreasing and its limit will be $0$.

My problem is that every time I get confused while it says $a_{2n}$ or $a_{2n-1}$, it is less intuitive for me than just "normal" $a_n$...

Appreciate your help!

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Each of the terms of the series is non-negative, since $a_n$ is increasing. Again by the monotonicity the sum increases if you replace the $\frac{1}{a_{2k}}$, by $\frac{1}{a_{2k+1}}$. But then the sum becomes $\frac{1}{a_1}-\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{a_{2n+1}}$. So, it is a sum of non-negative terms and bounded by $\frac{1}{a_1}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**HINT:**

Since $a_n$ is positive and increasing , then $\frac1{a_n}$ is positive and decreasing.  Moreover, we have

$$\sum_{n=1}^{2N}\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{a_n}=\sum_{n=1}^N \left(\frac1{a_{2n-1}}-\frac1{a_{2n}}\right)$$

Now use what you know about $\lim_{n\to \infty}a_n$.  Can you finish now?

Comment: Oh nice, so it is Leibniz series! I will try!

Comment: Yes.  Leibniz's rule applies here.

Comment: How do I convert the sum up to $2N$ to $\infty$?

Comment: Just takt the limit as $N\to \infty$.  Of course, you should check the case for which the upper limit is $2N+1$.  But since you know that $\lim_{N\to \infty}\frac1{a_{2N+1}}=0$, all works well.

Comment: Alright, sure! :)

Answer (score 2):

The fact that $(a_n)$ is unbounded is actually not needed, only that the sequence is positive and increasing.

First note that all terms $b_n = \frac{1}{a_{2n-1}}-\frac{1}{a_{2n}}$ are non-negative. Then verify that
$$
 \sum_{n=1}^N b_n = \frac{1}{a_1} + \underbrace{\left(-\frac{1}{a_2}+\frac{1}{a_3}\right)}_{\le 0}+  \cdots
+\underbrace{\left(-\frac{1}{a_{2N-2}}+\frac{1}{a_{2N-1}}\right)}_{\le 0}
 -\frac{1}{a_{2N}} \le \frac{1}{a_1} \, .
$$
So the partial sums of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n$ are increasing and bounded above.  It follows that the series is convergent.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Let

$$b_n=\frac1{a_{n-1}}-\frac1{a_{n}}$$

Each $b_n$ is non-negative, since $a_n$ is increasing.

Then your series is: $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_{2n}$$ But:

$$\sum_{n=2}^{2N} b_n\geq  \sum_{n=1}^{N} b_{2n}\geq 0$$

And $$\sum_{n=2}^{2N} b_n=\frac1{a_{1}}-\frac1{a_{2N}}.$$

Comment: The series of interest is $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (\color{red}{+}b_{2n})$, is it not?

Comment: Whoops, yes, somehow read it differently. @MarkViola

Comment: I've misread more problems than I can count.